# Adding and removing keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a textfield and when the user clicks on it, they will be presented with the keyboard. there is a `GO` button on the keyboard, and i want to write an `action` event to it.

1.) How can i write an `action` when the user clicks on this button

2.) when the keyboard is open, and when the user clicks on the background i need the keyboard to disappear, how can i do this programatically?

I have no code to demonstrate, i have only added a texfield, so the keyboard would appear by default once clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for performing some action on return of textfield/ Go button use following code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    //call Method when the GO button is pressed   

    return YES;
}
```

And when user touches on the background and keyboard should return - for that ,write below code

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[textFiedl resignFirstResponder];

}
```

hope your issues are resolved with this.

Answer (score 1):

A textfield is present whenever a UITextField or UITextView is the first responder. You can manually "show" the keyboard by calling becomeFirstResponder or "hide" it by resignFirstResponder.

In your case, Look at the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) reference; when the user hits "GO", the textFieldDidEndEditing: callback is invoked. In this method, you should call resignFirstResponder on the text field to hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For hiding the keyboard when you touch on the background you can write `[txtName resignFirstResponder];` where `txtName` is the reference name of the TextField.